# How to select the number of names equal to value and save the number of searches found into a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select the number of names in the database equal to "dog", and save the number of searches found into a variable php? e.g number of dogs found = 4;. Where I can store this as a variable.

So far I got this:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) FROM `profiledb` GROUP BY id
```

Comment: So you basically want to get the number of data-rows your query finds inside your database?

Comment: Yep, and store the number of queries recorded as a integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this, assuming your name field

```
SELECT name, COUNT(id) as number_of_searches FROM profiledb WHERE name = 'dog'
```

Comment: Thank you, going to check this as the answer soon. :)

Comment: Can i use a code to store the value of the number of rows counted as a variable, in order to use in PHP?

Comment: yes you need to use PHP to store that value in a variable...

Comment: This is what i have wrote, i'm having troubles echoing the value:  

$mysql_statementX = "SELECT name, COUNT(id) as number_of_searches FROM profiledb WHERE name = 'dog'";


 
 $mysql_commandX = mysql_query($mysql_statementX);
 
   while($rowX = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_commandX)){
  
  $applications = $rowX['number_of_searches'];
  
  echo $applications;
 
 }